# Can't debug javascript in PHPStorm 8

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, phpstorm

When I debug an `html` file with the PHPStorm built-in server, PHPStorm first installs the Firefox extension. The next time I try to debug JS I get the following error:

> The installed Firefox extension is incompatible with current PhpStorm version and will be updated. Please close Firefox if it is running and press "OK".

When I close firefox, and click `ok` firefox starts with the default start page.

I'm running OpenSuse 13.2 (same problems on Arch Linux) with PHPStorm 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Firefox is v33 or newer then yes, Firefox has removed old API for JavaScript debug and JetBrains browser extension / IDE does not support new one yet.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13801 -- star/vote/comment to get notified on progress.

---

If you need debug working right now in Firefox -- I may only suggest to install older Firefox version in a separate folder and use separate profile.

Alternatively -- try debugging in Google Chrome.

Comment: Thanks! I'll just use an firefox <33 version.